# Number of sessions filter in Google Analytics custom dashboard widget

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to create a widget to count number of users who have visited the site more 3 or more times within the time range.

I can easily do this when setting up a segment:

[image: Setting up segment]

*Note that the tooltip that appears for the question mark next to "Sessions" label defines it as "Total number of Sessions within the date range. A session is the period time a user is actively engaged with your website, app, etc. All usage data (Screen Views, Events, Ecommerce, etc.) is associated with a session."*

However, when creating a widget, I cannot find the option to define such a filter. The closest I can find is "Count of sessions", but there is not an arithmetic copmarison operator ([it is because Count of sessions is a string dimension](http://help.analyticsedge.com/googleanalytics/misunderstood-metrics-frequency-count-of-sessions/)),so I have to match it with this regex: `(^[3-9]$)|(^[0-9]{2,3}$)`:

[image: Setting up widget]

And the results are very different from the segment:

[image: Widget result]

Note 78.32% in widget vs 17.12% in segment.

**Question:** Is there a way to filter the users by the number of sessions within the time range in a dashboard widget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Count of Sessions` as you mentioned is a dimension not a metrics as we may expect it to be, it is incremented in the cookie with each session and is passed in GA as such. To elaborate :

Suppose we have 3 users, following is their visit log :

```
User A - Visit's 1st time | Count Of Session =1 
User A - Visit's 2nd time | Count Of Session =2 
User A - Visit's 3rd time | Count Of Session =3
User B - Visit's 1st time | Count Of Session =1
User B - Visit's 2nd time | Count Of Session =2
User C - Visit's 1st time | Count Of Session =1
```

Now if we make a report of Users group by Count Of Sessions, we may have something like this :

```
Count Of Sessions |  Users
    1             |    3 
    2             |    2 
    3             |    1
```

For your problem it would be difficult to present this in a single value, data would make more sense if you could show a tabular view, I've tried to address your case with following widget :

[image]

It's important to note that the number of users you see against the `Count Of Sessions` is not exclusive, to have the exclusive users against each `Count Of Sessions` we could simply :

> Users having n only sessions = (Users with n Count Of Sessions - Users with (n+1) Count Of Sessions

[image]

So, Users having only 3 sessions would be 1,062,191 (3,962,517 - 2,900,326)

Comment: Thanks! The exact regexp should be `(^1$)|(^2$)` (so we don't exclude values such as 10, 11, 21...)

Comment: Do you know if this count of sessions dimesion is within the selected date range?